# Can't install CiviCRM on Wordpress (error Database)

Tags: wordpress, error, database, install, hosting-providers

I try a several times to install CiviCRM on my Wordpress. But the Check before show problems with the database. I checked everything a several times but no success.

Wordpress is running on a hosting at "Strato"
See the screenshot for more informations.

Can anybody help me whats going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried leaving the MySQL server as localhost? I've only had to ever change that setting maybe a handful of times in hundreds of installs.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of observations:

1. You may need to double-check that you can reach your MySQL database, since CiviCRM apparently can't (it's confusing since it reports that it can't connect, yet various operations can be done)
2. Your MySQL user needs to be able to create triggers. You probably need to contact your host to request this capability.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your fast reply.

in the mheanwhile i checked again the DB informations, checked again the wp-config and copy all infos from there.

Result the same.

in the meanwhile i receive also a answer from the hoster.
They said at my hosting package i didnt have the rights for the DB. They suggest me of course to rent a virtual server ...or to download the DB and configure local and then upload again.

Can you tell me if this way is possible, what exactly i have to configure at the db?